# Why is radiation of a particular frequency most intense in black body radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, photon-emission

Why is radiation of a particular frequency more intense than other frequencies in black body radiation? Does this mean that most electrons in the object are emitting photons of that frequency?

Answer (score 1):

[Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) shows why there is a peak in the black body spectrum: the radiation intensity increases with frequency, as the density of the photon states, but the number of atoms/electrons emitting radiation of highfrequency decreases exponentially with temperature, as per Boltzmann distribution.

Indeed, the atoms/electrons have different energies, distributed according to [Boltzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) distribution.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is radiation of a particular frequency more intense than other frequencies in black body radiation?

Every body has a (mean) temperature that is approximately proportional to the mean value of the excitations of the subatomic particles involved. When the electron receives the energy of a photon, it is excited and emits a photon again when it falls back. The re-emitted photons have different wavelengths. It turns out that there is a dissipation of frequencies and it is in the nature of black bodies that this dissipation does not lead to many peaks (with some colours) but has the typical graph with only one rounded maximum.

> Does this mean that most electrons in the object are emitting photons of that frequency?

The electrons emit photons of all frequencies along the frequencies shown in the graph with a maximum at a certain frequency.

> If this is the case, can the electrons of atoms of an object posses different amounts of energy?

Yes.